# How to set GridLayout for WinForms control i.e. Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

How can one set GridLayout known from Java or Wpf in WinForms control? Is it available by default or does it require writing some code (custom LayoutEngine implementation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is available by default. If you are using Visual Studio, just drag it from toolbox to your form and set properties.

Comment: I found it eventually. It little confusing that it is called TableLayoutPanel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Windows Forms work totally different from Java and WPF forms. One of thier differences is that there's no layout for windows forms whatsoever, instead there's this ability that you can place a control whenever you would like using its location property.